# Talend TAC export of list of tasks

Tags: talend

I would like to take an export of the list of jobs that are created as tasks under job conductor in TAC along with its configurations. Is this possible and if yes, please support. I am using the Enterprise edition of Talend V5.6

Comment: If you are using the Enterprise Edition, you should be able to open a ticket with Talend to ask this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an API to query the TAC called MetaServletCaller. Using this API, you can send a command to get a list of the tasks deployed in Job Conductor.
The API can be called from a url in a browser, or by calling MetaServletCaller.sh (or .bat) script from your Talend installation.
The command to get this list is `listTasks`.
Here is a tutorial on how to do that : http://edwardost.github.io/talend/di/2015/05/28/Using-the-TAC-API/

Answer (score 0):

All TAC configuration is linked to DB tables. Just connect to this database (you can get the name through TAC, in Configuration>Database menu), and have a look at "executiontask" table, it contains all jobs deployed in Job Conductor, with Context/Job Version, etc.

Comment: No direct options thru TAC ?

Comment: I don't think so.